# Date render from Firestore

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I want to render a date from Firestore but it displays errors when I try to use `toDate` or `tolocaleString`, is there anyway I can get the date not in seconds or nanoseconds. If I use date only it says I should use an array render.

Below is my code and `console.log` (when I use `toDate` inside the function it does work but when I use it for a return it is not working).

```html
<Text style={{fontSize: 18, color: "black", alignContent: "flex-start", paddingLeft: @}}>Full name: {user && user?.fullName}</Text>
<Text style={{fontSize: 18, color: "black", alignContent: "flex-start", paddingLeft: @}}>Email : {user && user?.email}</Text>
<Text style={{fontSize: 18, color: "black", alignContent: "flex-start", paddingLeft: @}}>Gender : {user && user?.gender}</Text>
<Text style={{fontSize: 18, color: "black", alignContent: "flex-start", paddingLeft: @}}>Date Of Birth : {user && user?.date.seconds}</Text>
```

```
Object {
  "bdate": t {
  "nanoseconds": 0,
  "seconds": 1472788800,
},
  "connectCode": "G7BDM",
  "date": t {
  "nanoseconds": 0,
  "seconds": 1575262800,
},
  "email": "",
  "fullName": "",
  "gender": "none",
  "id": "PB6gVEcyBYU1D33S9aqVy4LtRi82",
  "image": null,
  "userLinks": Array [],
}
2019-12-02T05:00:00.000Z
```

```
const usersRef = firebase.firestore().collection('users')
const getUser = async () => {
    const {uid} = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    try {
        const documentSnapshot = await usersRef
        .doc(uid)
        .get();
        
    const userData = documentSnapshot.data();
    console. log(userData);
    console. log(userData.date.toDate());

    setUser(userData);

  } catch(error) {
  alert(error);
  }
};
// Get user on mount
useEffect(() => {
    getUser();
}, []);
```

Comment: Hi. Please do not edit "SOLVED" into the title. Instead, mark an answer: click the checkmark next to the answer that gave you the solution you wanted. That will mark your question solved the proper way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code, check if it works

```
<Text style={{fontSize: 18, color: "black", alignContent: "flex-start", paddingLeft: 0}}>
    Date Of Birth: {user && user.date && user.date.seconds && new Date(user.date.seconds * 1000).toLocaleDateString("en-US")}
</Text>
```

Comment: @HòangVũũ Can you please mark the answer as correct? It will help others who may fall on the same issue. Thanks.